# How do i get parent model from child model in Odoo 9?

Tags: listview, model, odoo-9

I'm creating an custom module to add new row into tree view.

I'm trying to add a new row with parent model "project.project" into tree view "project.task"

and What I've done so far is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="ListView">
        <t t-jquery="thead" t-operation="before">
            <t t-if="options.action.res_model=='project.task'">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary o_list_button_add" accesskey="C">
                    <!-- I'd like to add project.project's custom field below -->
                    <t t-esc="project.project.custom.field"/>
                </button>
            </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

I'd like to add custom field to the button name.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it like this?

```
<!-- I'd like to add project.project's custom field below -->
<t t-esc="o.project.project.custom.field"/>
```

Comment: Yes I did but It doesn't work. It makes an error "project is not defined"